# I need a way to get a Random number (0-10) from an array then get the following 2 subsequent #'s. Such as 7,8,9. 3,4,5 etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I'm making a 1-D battleship game where there is only 1, 1x10 row so I want to generate a random #(0-10) each game but the next 2 numbers must be right beside it because its a ship. I've been trying lots of different options with no success so far. This code grabs 3 random #'s with no-repeats, also important, but the numbers aren't next to each other. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
const nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const shuffled = nums.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
let selected = shuffled.slice(0, 3);
console.log(selected);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random index and use `Array#slice` to get the three numbers starting from there.

```js
const nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let rand = Math.random() * (nums.length - 2) | 0;
let randomThree = nums.slice(rand, rand + 3);
console.log(randomThree);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getShipPosition(shipSize, nums) {
  const startPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nums.length - shipSize + 1));
  return nums.slice(startPosition, startPosition + shipSize)
}

const nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
console.log(getShipPosition(3, nums));
```

Comment: like `return nums.slice(startPosition, startPosition+shipSize)`?

Comment: @Thomas, Right. I just modified the version to use .slice().